# IR beam break sensor

Tags: light, proximity-sensor

[image]I want to make an "IR beam break sensor" as per attached schematic.

I would also like to add some sort of “time delay” to the schematic. When the beam breaks and the relay gets activated, I would like the relay to stay activated for a couple of seconds after the object has passed through the beam.

Anyone got any ideas has to how I can achieve that?
Cheers
Spike
[image]

Comment: That won't work over more than trivial distance.  Do some web searches on IR receivers which look for 38 KHz pulses and find one that accepts a continuous pulse train rather than looking for the bursty pattern of TV remote codes.

Comment: That circuit will be easily confused by passing shadows from sunlight.

Comment: I think a ralay cannot be connected to NE555 directly. Use "solid relay" or "transistor key"

Comment: Bring the circuit to a typical monostable. There is circuit isn't working without complex change. See http://www.circuitbasics.com/555-timer-basics-monostable-mode/ for example. Search question "NE555 one pulse" ready circuits. Input 2 TRI can not be nc.

Comment: @nick_n_a An NE555 can output up to 200 mA (both source and sink); A lot of [signal relays](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/signal-relays-up-to-2-amps/189) have a low enough coil current that I can envision it working properly.

Comment: The gap will only be small between the ir diode and the photo diode approx 25mm , and will inside a casing, no hardly any light will hit the photo diode , am attaching a revised schematic ! .